# GPO - Block 3rd party cookies for IE 8

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, internet-explorer, cookies, privacy

I am trying to find some settings in GPOs that explicitly say, "Block 3rd Party cookies" in IE.  I am looking under policies>admin template>windows components>IE> IE control panel>Security page.  Should I look elsewhere for these?  I don't really see this under individual zones either.  I could possibly do this just by configuring the default user profile's privacy settings but I would rather do this with a GPO.  Has anyone does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this under:

> User Configuration\Windows Settings\Internet Explorer Maintenance\Security\Security Zones and Content Ratings

Comment: Excellent! I just have to click import, modify, and then setup the policy the way I want it to be. Much easier then trying to edit the default user.  So many answers I saw out and about were talking about GPP registry settings, default user edit, etc.  This is much cleaner.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: That was another option using GPP and editing the registry setting there, but GPOs make life easy :)

Comment: Just noticed this states 2k3 only... I am looking to do this for 2008 servers.